# PHP/MySql: loop Query to insert rows and add sum on the weight (e.g 200 kgs max) and continue same with next row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops

I am trying to add rows to the new table.

I am using a foreach loop to insert the data and I am able to insert the data. I am also able to reach to the limit and add a new row. But the issue is once the loop is over, it adds individual row and does not add to the limit i want.

I am not too sure how can I add my table here. But please find the code below:

```
$fetchRecordRS = DB::select("
Select `ID`
     , `DeliveryAddress`
     , `Postzone`
     , `CarrierID`
     , `DeliveryInstruction`
     , `JobID`
     , `JobName`
     , Quantity
     , `Bundlesize`
     , SUM(Bundles) as 'SumBundles'
     , SUM(Items) as 'SumItems'
     , WeightKgs
     , TotalWeightKgs 
     , SUM(WeightKgs) AS 'FixWeight'
     , Notes 
  FROM UpdatedCsvFiles
 WHERE DeliveryAddress != 'PLEASE LEAVE IN WAREHOUSE' 
   AND JobID != 0 
 GROUP 
    BY DeliveryAddress
     , JobName 
     , CarrierID
 ORDER 
    BY CarrierID
     , DeliveryAddress ASC
");


foreach ($fetchRecordRS as $row_FetchRecordRS) {  
    $id = $row_FetchRecordRS->ID;
    $carr_ID = $row_FetchRecordRS->CarrierID;
    $address = $row_FetchRecordRS->DeliveryAddress;
    $potzone = $row_FetchRecordRS->Postzone;
    $instruction = $row_FetchRecordRS->DeliveryInstruction;
    $quantity = $row_FetchRecordRS->Quantity;
    $jobID = $row_FetchRecordRS->JobID;
    $jobName = $row_FetchRecordRS->JobName;
    $bundlesize = $row_FetchRecordRS->Bundlesize;
    $bundle = $row_FetchRecordRS->SumBundles;
    $items = $row_FetchRecordRS->SumItems;
    //$num = $row_FetchRecordRS->FixWeight;
    //$suburb = $row_FetchRecordRS->Suburb;
    //$row_FetchRecordRS->TotalWeightKgs
    $num = $row_FetchRecordRS->TotalWeightKgs;
    $notes = $row_FetchRecordRS->Notes;
    $num = $row_FetchRecordRS->FixWeight;


    if ($num + $total > 200) {
        echo ($num + $total) . "in Van " . $i ;
        $sqltransitlist = DB::select("Insert INTO TransitList(genID, total) Values ('$i','$total')");
        // loop A
        foreach ($arr as $data) {
            // echo "<br> first loop: " . $i;
            $sqlquerytest = DB::select("Insert INTO GenerateRun(CarrierID, DeliveryAddress, Postzone, DeliveryInstruction, Quantity, JobID,
                                                              JobName, Notes, Bundlesize, Bundles, Items,   FinalWeight, LodingZoneID)
                                                              VALUES('"  . $data['CarrierID'] ."','"  . $data['DeliveryAddress'] ."','" . $data['Postzone'] .
                "','"  .  $data['DeliveryInstruction']. "','" .$data['Quantity']  . "','"  . $data['JobID'] .
                "','"  . $data['JobName'] . "','"  .$data['Notes']  . "','" . $data['Bundlesize']. "','"  .$data['Bundles'] .
                "','"    . $data['Items'] ."','"  .$data['FixWeight']."','" .$i ."')");
        }

        $arr = array();
        $i++;
        $total = 0;
    }

    $total += $num;
    $arr[] = array('CarrierID' => $carr_ID, 'DeliveryAddress' => $address, 'Postzone' => $potzone,
        'DeliveryInstruction' => $instruction, 'Notes' => $notes, 'Quantity' => $quantity, 'JobID' => $jobID,
        'JobName' => $jobName, 'Bundlesize' => $bundlesize, 'Bundles' => $bundle, 'Items' => $items,
        'FixWeight' => $num);

}

if ($total > 0) {
    $sqltransitlist = DB::select("Insert INTO TransitList(genID, total) Values ('$i','$total')");
    // loop B
    foreach ($arr as $data) {
        // echo "<br> Second loop: " . $i;
        $sqlquerytest = DB::select("Insert INTO GenerateRun(CarrierID, DeliveryAddress, Postzone, DeliveryInstruction, Quantity, JobID,
                                                   JobName, Notes, Bundlesize, Bundles, Items,   FinalWeight, LodingZoneID)
                                                   VALUES('"  . $data['CarrierID'] ."','"  . $data['DeliveryAddress'] ."','" . $data['Postzone'] .
            "','"  .  $data['DeliveryInstruction']. "','" .$data['Quantity']  . "','"  . $data['JobID'] .
            "','"  . $data['JobName'] . "','"  .$data['Notes']  . "','" . $data['Bundlesize']. "','"  .$data['Bundles'] .
            "','"    . $data['Items'] ."','"  .$data['FixWeight']."','" .$i ."')");

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: *" it adds individual row and does not add to the limit i want."*..... what is the limit you want in your code ?

Comment: `$arr` has only 1 element , that is why `foreach ($arr as $data)` got executed 1 time only, I guess you wanted that line `$arr[] = array('C ........` in loop `A` to add multiple elements.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries